# required variable, found String java

Tags: java

I am trying to read in a user input as a string. Parse it into an int, then whatever number (0-3) that the user input, I want to replace that index of the array with a card.  Here is the code

```
    public void discard(String text) {

    int i = Integer.parseInt(text);

    for(int p = 0; p < 4; p++){
        if(i == p){
            hand[p].getCard() = card; // This is where I recieve the Error.
        }
    }
}
```

Anything that will help me correct and understand my mistake will be helpful, Thanks!

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Post your stack error

Comment: The error says that is requires a variable and it found a string. *Incompatible Types*

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you write a method that calls for a `String`, and the first (and only) thing you do with that `String` is parse an `int` out of it?  Why not just have the method call for an `int`?

Comment: `public void discard(int i);` and if you really need a method that does this with a `String`, then just overload it with `public void discard(String text) { discard(Integer.parseInt(text)); }`

Comment: Also, your `for` loop doesn't really make any sense.  Get rid of it, and do `if(i>0 && i<4) { hand[i].setCard(card); }`

Comment: ^^ Thank you! You are backing up my side of it... The for loop was given and we are required to leave it and use it there... I think its stupid.

Answer (score 5):

I think you meant to do this

```
hand[p].setCard(card);
```

because the below piece of code doesn't really make sense. You can't possibly assign a value to a value(retrieved by `getCard()`) method. That is why you got the error that it expected a variable on the left hand side of the assignment operator, but instead found a String there.

```
hand[p].getCard() = card;
```

Comment: I must be having a long day to have not noticed that... So stupid of a question to even ask on here ahah. Thank you Sir.

Comment: @NerdsRaisedHand - Happens often. No problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, you're probably going to to need to change:

```
hand[p].getCard() = card;
```

to

```
hand[p].setCard(card);
```

You can't assign to a getter.

---

Also, this code:

```
for (int p = 0; p < 4; p++) {
    if (i == p){
        // do something with p
    }
}
```

Can be replaced with

```
// do something with i
```

Comment: There will be a problem if `i` has an value beyond *4* (which might be the length of the array).